# Why can't まちがいなく失敗 mean 'a zero-mistakes失敗'?

Tags: meaning, translation, parsing, interpretation

失敗するのを**気にしたら**、**まちがいなく**失敗してしまう。
=If we think of failure, we will certainly fail.

When I read the example the first time, thinking it's a proverb, I interpreted it like:

*If you **mind** failure, you will fall in/encounter/make the **no-mistakes** failure.*

What prevents 'grammatically' such interpretation?

---

---

Edit:

> **Comment on @shingo.nakanishi answer:**
> Can I say [**雨ない**年だった.] for 'It was a **no-rain**/rainless year.'?
>
> If YES, then why can't we think of まちがいない as a 'whole word' that modifies 失敗 in [失敗するのを気にしたら、**まちがいない**失敗してしまう。] also?

> **Comment on @naruto answer:**
> Is [雨な**く**年だった.] for 'It was a rainless**ly** year' correct in Japanese? 
> If YES, then why can't we consider まちがいなく as an adverbial that modifies 失敗 in [失敗するのを**気にしたら**、**まちがいなく**失敗してしまう。] also?

Comment: 間違いなく is kind of a set phrase

Comment: @AeonAkechi Literally speaking (regardless of the set-phrase fact), is my interpretation of the sentence correct?

Comment: What do you achieve by arguing for a literal interpretation if no natives would use it that way?

Comment: @Leebo If you have a list of all Japanese set phrases, this may well solve my problem, because I don't know when and where I'd encounter a set phrase all of a sudden. Actually I can't recognise set phrases in sentences.

Comment: @Leebo I think many new Japanese learners have my problem:
https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/4bck3z/list_of_set_phrases/

Comment: `Why can't まちがいなく失敗 mean 'zero mistakes'失敗?` Why can't "It will fail without fail." mean 'zero 失敗'失敗?

Comment: @Chocolate It can. But since you suggested that [雨なく年だった.] is a wrong sentence, and since く-form is not actually an adjective as you suggested, then, taking that into assumption, my interpretation would be wrong right?

Answer (score 3):

You translated it as "no mistake", which is a **noun**, but you should notice なく is the **ku-form** (≒adverbial form). The very literal translation of 間違いなく is "error-less-**ly**" or "in an error-free manner", which is why it is usually translated as "certainly", "undoubtedly" or "without doubt" in English.

---

**EDIT:** The basic rule you have to keep in mind is actually very simple. The 連体形 (i-form) modifies a noun (thus called "adjectival"), and the 連用形 (ku-form) modifies a verb (thus called "adverbial"). For example 速**い**車 is "a fast car" and this 速い/fast is adjectival because it modifies a noun. 速**く**走る is "to run fast", and this 速く/fast is called adverbial because it modifies a verb (although 速く is a form of an adjective).

If you said 間違いない失敗をする, it would mean something funny and paradoxical like "to make an un-mistaken mistake" or "to make an error-less error". That's not something you want to say. Here 間違いなく must modify 失敗する **adverbially**.

Comment: I always thought of く-form as merely used for conjunction purposes and never thought it actually makes adjectives adverbs.
But @l'électeur insists that it is still an adjective:
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/the-meaning-of-%E3%81%8F#comment32056_14843

Comment: Is [雨なく年だった.] for 'It was a rainlessly year' correct in Japanese?
If YES, then why can't we consider まちがいなく as an adverbial that modifies 失敗 in [失敗するのを気にしたら、まちがいなく失敗してしまう。] also?

Comment: @raruna, l'électeur is saying it's not an adverb but 連用形(adverbial/continuative from) of an adjective...

Comment: @raruna, `Is [雨なく年だった.] for 'It was a rainlessly year' correct in Japanese? If YES`  -- No, I'm afraid not. (Is "It was a rainless*ly* year" correct in English?)

Comment: @reruna There are standalone, non-inflectable, "pure" adverbs such かなり and しばらく, whereas there are also "adverbial forms of adjectives" such as 美しく and 速く. The latter are not in dictionaries because it's a form (ku-form) of an adjective (this is what l'électeur is saying), but these "adverbial words" all work similarly in that it modifies the next verb/adjective. "Rainless year" is 雨のない年, and there is no need to use a ku-form because there is no verb in this phrase in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

**間違いなく** means **without a doubt**

In this case, **without** is a good translation of **ない**.

"ない" denies "間違い", not "失敗".

If you deny "失敗" in Japanese, you get "失敗しない".

**There is no** such expression as "なく失敗" or "ない失敗", so you can't read it wrong.

The Japanese language is quite different from the English word order, so **it's easy to misread it if you read it in the English word order**.

On the other hand, This makes it very difficult for Japanese to learn English.

In Japanese, the pattern of negative words coming from the front is for kanji such as "非", "不", "否". As you can see from the fact that it is a Kanji, this usage comes from ancient China.

sample:

- 非常識
- 不必要
- 否決

On the other hand, put "ない" behind the word.

- 非常識（常識がない）
- 不必要（必要ない）
- 否決（承認しない）

response to comments:

> Can I say [雨ない年だった.] for 'It was a no rain/rainless year.'?

"雨ない年だった" and "雨なく年だった" is very unnatural.

"雨のない年だった", "雨の降らない年だった" or "雨が降らない年だった" is natural.

I can't explain why, by the way, but you can't say "まちがいな**い**失敗してしまう。". Change it to **く** to be correct.

If you must use **い**, you can express it as:

「失敗するのを気にしたら、失敗してしまうよ。間違いな**い**ね。」（spoken language）

I don't know why. I'm Japanese, so it comes naturally to me.

By the way, you can use **く** in this case.

「失敗するのを気にしたら、失敗してしまうよ。間違いな**く**ね。」（spoken language）

Or something like this:

失敗するのを気にしたら、失敗してしまう。これは間違いな**い**ことです。

In this case, you **can not** say これは間違いな**く**ことです.  Again, I don't know why.

But if you use "そう" instead of "こと", you can use **く** not **い**.

失敗するのを気にしたら、失敗してしまう。これは間違いな**く**そうです。

I can only give you same example. I can't explain.

By the way, "間違いな**い**そうです", It means that I heard that way.

Comment: Can I say [雨ない年だった.] for 'It was a no rain/rainless year.'?
If YES, then why can't we think of まちがいない as a 'whole word' that modifies 失敗 in [失敗するのを気にしたら、まちがいない失敗してしまう。]  also?